SQL Server 2019 tempdb files won't shrink
I have a tempdb configured with 8 datafiles and 1 log file. Originally the datafiles were all set to the same size, however, they have grown over time and are now all different sizes. I was able to shrink a few back to the original file size, but there are 4 that won't shrink.
All the files show 99% free space in them. I've verified that there are no open transactions in the database and that there is nothing currently using tempdb.
How can I shrink those last few -- I wouldn't worry about it at all except the database is approaching the 2 TB limit.
Thanks!

don't take these close votes the wrong way... they should help get your question in front of a more targeted group of experts so you get can get a better answer more quickly.

tempdb is recreated when the SQL Server service is restarted - so that is the quickest and easiest way.

It may be quick and easy, but this is a production box, so that's not optimal. Thanks anyway.

Can you provide more info? What is the SHRINK command you're using? Can you include the output of "select * from tempdb.sys.database_files"?

Create a backup of tempdb, then shrink it.

please don't do this - just the thought of it hurts by DBA heart

@MarcelloMiorelli true it is probably left as is, growing the db file is more costly than reusing empty space, but just in case the OP does have a valid reason, I took the question at face value.
